# Hover image automatically hover out?

Tags: jquery, hover, rollover

the buttons are the six square images on top.

http://wthdesign.net/test/rollover/services.html

the code i use:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.originalImg,rollOverImg').hover(

  function () {
    $(this).next().stop().animate({left: '0'}, 500, function(){});
    console.log("in");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).next().stop().animate({left: '90px'}, 500, function(){});
    console.log("out");
  }

);
```

my html:

```
<div class="slicesBoxesTop"><img class="originalImg" src="images/home.png" /><img class="rollOverImg" src="http://makingdesign.com.au/images/mickslice1.gif" width="90" height="90" /></div> 
<div class="slicesBoxTop2"><img  class="originalImg" src="images/home.png" /><img class="rollOverImg" src="http://makingdesign.com.au/images/paulslice2.gif" width="90" height="90" /></div>
<div class="sliceTop3"><img  class="originalImg" src="images/home.png" /><img class="rollOverImg" src="http://makingdesign.com.au/images/mickslice2.gif" width="90" height="90" /></div>
<div class="sliceTop4"><img  class="originalImg" src="images/home.png" /><img class="rollOverImg" src="http://makingdesign.com.au/images/paulslice3.gif" width="90" height="90" /></div>
<div class="sliceTopbox5"><img  class="originalImg" src="images/home.png" /><img class="rollOverImg" src="http://makingdesign.com.au/images/mickslice3.gif" width="92" height="92" /></div>
```

For some reason it rollout automatically even when my cursor still in hovering the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem: you have two selector in hover... `$('.originalImg,.rollOverImg')` so when you move your mouse to rollOverImg...the origninalImg mouseleave function is called ..

solution,

name all you divs with same class and use hover for entire `<div>` .not tested but this should work.

try this

**html**

```
<div class="slicesBoxesTop divClass"><img class="originalImg"..
<div class="slicesBoxTop2 divClass"><img class="originalImg" ...
 ..so on
```

**jquery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.divClass').hover(
   function () {
       $(this).find('.rollOverImg').stop().animate({left: '0'}, 500, function(){});
     console.log("in");
   },
   function () {
     $(this).find('.rollOverImg').stop().animate({left: '90px'}, 500, function(){});
     console.log("out");
   }

 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your selector is wrong:

`$('.originalImg,rollOverImg').hover`

Should be:

`$('.originalImg,.rollOverImg').hover`

Second, your 'rollOverImg' overlaps the 'originalImg' when you call animate causing the "mouse out" portion of your hover event to fire. You want to put separate handlers on your original & rollover images:

```
$(".originalImg").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).next().stop().animate({left: '0'}, 500, function(){});
});
$(".rollOverImg").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).prev().stop().animate({left: '90px'}, 500, function(){});
});
```

Comment: the image will slide in but when i mouse out it doesnt go back to its original position...